# Execution of UPDATE based on condition

Tags: mysql

Is there a way in MySQL to insert a condition based on which the entire UPDATE query will be executed? I know that you can use IF or CASE within the query itself to insert different values, but I'm talking about this scenario:

IF ( condition is true ) UPDATE ...

Let's say I wanted to validate data and execute the UPDATE based on result (I know it's a bad idea and data validation should be done scripting wise, I'm just reviewing the theoretical possibilities). Like here below where I test a value against regexp to check if it's numerical value:

UPDATE executed:

```
IF ( "12345" REGEXP "[0-9]+" ) UPDATE table SET numdata = "12345" WHERE...;
```

UPDATE not executed:

```
IF ( "a1234" REGEXP "[0-9]+" ) UPDATE table SET numdata = "a1234" WHERE...;
```

Thanks,

Prez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the REGEXP in your `WHERE` clause:

```
DECLARE mynumdata varchar(10) = "a1234";
UPDATE table SET numdata = mynumdata
WHERE @numdata REGEXP "[0-9]+"
  AND <other update conditions>;
```

Comment: Thank you both for answers, now it seems so obvious to me. I picked the selected answer based on 1 second difference between submissions :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to add the condition to the WHERE clause.

So if you originally had

`UPDATE table SET numdata = "a1234" WHERE id=1`

you could write this as

`UPDATE table SET numdata = "a1234" WHERE id=1 AND "1234" REGEXP "[0-9]+"`